# how to conect raspberry standard monitor to the pi?

Tags: display, cable

i bought this http://www.amazon.in/Raspberry-Pi-Screen-Display-Finger-Capacitive/dp/B01BKOTRFI/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1460391670&sr=8-1&keywords=raspberry++pi+monitor#productDetails 
i cant connect it, there are no images or documentation either to guide, it had a little tips on a paper that i bought which is useless.
On internet most links are for monitor with cables, but here i am with a strange strip. i have hdmi to hdmi cable for which there is no plug.
there is no cable either to charge it, so i guess it draws power from main source via GPIO via raspberry.

> Do i have to use the GPIO?
>   for usual monitors do they have a power cable, if so the adapter is ALREADY connected to the raspberry, will i have to attach a 3plug adapter which i have, which i can then connect to USB adapter?

i have https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/the-eagerly-awaited-raspberry-pi-display/ i dont know if method (2) or (3) is for me. i do have 4 wires,that have black pins at the end, and also 4 screws.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tK-w-wDvRTg

Comment: dear steve, i do not have a power bank! And also an extra power cable! i bought embedded starter kit which has a white USB adapter, and its cable only. In the bought monitor they didnt give that "LITTLE Plug" cable for power.

Comment: In short i can power raspberry only. why dont they give a damn cable for power.

Answer (score 1):

Did the adapter board shown in the picture on amazon come with it?  It will be required for it to work.  From I'm seeing it seems that you need to connect the ribbon cable from the adaptor board to your DSI port on the raspberry pi.  Look on your raspberry pi and just below the DSI port it will say "display".  This is the port you want to connect the ribbon cable to.

For powering the monitor you have three options.  Using two separate uUSB power supplies, daisy chaining USB from the adapter board to the PI.  Or jumping power off of your PI VIA the GPIO pins.

I'm assuming you do not have any spare uUSB cables so I would suggest jumping off of the GPIO pins (Option 3).  You will need two female to female jumper wires.  You can get a pack of them on Amazon for about 5 bucks.  Connect the ground pin on your PI to the ground pin on the adapter, and connect the 5V pin from the pi to the 5V pin on the adapter (As shown in the picture in the link you posted).  Then run the suggested commands and reboot.

Answer (score 1):

> but here i am with a strange strip.

You are supposed to plug that strip into the display port on your Pi. Not the HDMI, but a little plug on the Pi itself.
[image]
Also it looks like you should plug some wires into the GPIO to power the screen.
The official instruction video is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6HvWXQsBeHk).